# Efficient computation of the least-squares algorithm in NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, least-squares

I need to solve a large set of linear systems, in the least-squares sense. I am having trouble in understanding the difference in computational efficiency of `numpy.linalg.lstsq(a, b)`, `np.dot(np.linalg.pinv(a), b)` and the mathematical implementation.

I use the following matrices:

```
h=np.random.random((50000,100))
a=h[:,:-1].copy()
b=-h[:,-1].copy()
```

and the results of the algorithms are:

---

```
# mathematical implementation
%%timeit
np.dot(np.dot(np.linalg.inv(np.dot(a.T,a)),a.T),b)
```

10 loops, best of 3: **36.3 ms** per loop

---

```
# numpy.linalg.lstsq implementation
%%timeit
np.linalg.lstsq(a, b)[0]
```

10 loops, best of 3: **103 ms** per loop

---

```
%%timeit
np.dot(np.linalg.pinv(a), b)
```

1 loop, best of 3: **216 ms** per loop

---

Why is there a difference?

Comment: Why they should be the same?

Comment: mathematically they return the same result

Comment: @blaz Are you looking to optimize them further or are you satisfied with these approaches and just trying to understand the timing differences?

Comment: I am just trying to understand first :).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The routine [`lstsq`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html) handles any systems: over-determined, under-determined, or well-determined. Its output is what you'd get from pinv(a)*b but it is faster than computing the pseudoinverse. Here's why:

General advice: *do not compute the inverse matrix unless you actually need it*. Solving a system for a particular right hand side is faster than inverting its matrix.

Yet, your approach via solving a<sup>T</sup>a = a<sup>T</sup>b is faster, even though you  are inverting a matrix. What gives? The thing is, inverting a<sup>T</sup>a is only valid when a has full column rank. So you've restricted the problem to this particular situation, and gained in speed as a trade off for less generality and, as I show below, for less safety.

But inverting a matrix is still inefficient. If you know that a has full column rank, the following is faster than any of your three attempts:

```
np.linalg.solve(np.dot(a.T, a), np.dot(a.T, b))
```

---

That said,  `lstsq` is still preferable to the above when dealing with poorly conditioned matrices. Forming the product a<sup>T</sup>a basically squares the condition number, so you are more likely to get meaningless results. Here is a cautionary example, using SciPy's linalg module (which is essentially equivalent to NumPy's but has more methods):

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.linalg as sl
a = sl.hilbert(10)    # a poorly conditioned square matrix of size 10
b = np.arange(10)     # right hand side
sol1 = sl.solve(a, b)
sol2 = sl.lstsq(a, b)[0]
sol3 = sl.solve(np.dot(a.T, a), np.dot(a.T, b))
```

Here `lstsq` gives almost the same output as `solve` (the unique solution of this system). Yet, `sol3` is totally wrong because of numeric issues (which you won't even be warned about).

sol1:

```
  [ -9.89821788e+02,   9.70047434e+04,  -2.30439738e+06,
     2.30601241e+07,  -1.19805858e+08,   3.55637424e+08,
    -6.25523002e+08,   6.44058066e+08,  -3.58346765e+08,
     8.31333426e+07]
```

sol2:

```
  [ -9.89864366e+02,   9.70082635e+04,  -2.30446978e+06,
     2.30607638e+07,  -1.19808838e+08,   3.55645452e+08,
    -6.25535946e+08,   6.44070387e+08,  -3.58353147e+08,
     8.31347297e+07]
```

sol3:

```
  [  1.06913852e+03,  -4.61691763e+04,   4.83968833e+05,
    -2.08929571e+06,   4.55280530e+06,  -5.88433943e+06,
     5.92025910e+06,  -5.56507455e+06,   3.62262620e+06,
    -9.94523917e+05]
```